# Error: Cannot find module 'mongodb/node_modules/bson'

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using node 8.1.2 with mongoose 4.11. On starting the app, I am getting these errors:

```
D:\express_learn\LAM>node app.js
module.js:487
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'mongodb/node_modules/bson'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\express_learn\LAM\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\objectid.js:8:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)

D:\express_learn\LAM>
```

I tried the following solution from [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2718)

```
npm install node-gyp -g
npm cache clean
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

But still getting the same error.

Here is `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "learn-about-me",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.6.5",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.3.2",
    "ejs": "^1.0.0",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "express-session": "^1.7.6",
    "mongoose": "^4.11.0",
    "passport": "^0.2.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is in the `package.json`? Are you possibly seeing any errors when you run `npm install`? Looking for conflicts here between maybe trying to include both mongoose and the core driver as dependencies as well as compile errors that may show up in the install process. Clean again and be sure to copy any errors and include them in your post. No screenshots please.

Comment: Updated the question with `package.json`. I am only seeing this error when I try to start app via `node app.js`.

Comment: Try removing `package-lock.json` and run `npm install` again.

Comment: Do what robert says and also make it `npm install --verbose` and copy any errors you see in the output.

Comment: @NeilLunn, clearing the cache and removing the `package-lock.json` did the trick. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to resolve the issue

```
npm cache clean --force
rm -f package-lock.json
node install
```